# Optimising the reducing of nested objects and arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, reduce

I'm writing an army movement algorithm for a game. I have working code however it has three nested 'for' statements iterating over fairly large object collections. This will drive animation and will be run at approx 60fps) I'm looking to optimise this for performance.

The starting position is an array (**army**) of objects (**units**). Each unit object has two attributes:

(**unit.pathChain**) - an array of arrays denoting the full path chain between two nodes (e.g. moving from nodeA to nodeC via nodeB would look like this [[A, B],[B,C]]).

(**unit.distance**) - an integer describing this distance travelled on the first path of the path chain only.

The challenge of the algorithm is to reduce all possible paths with their minimum distance travelled (distances are considered to be 0 for all paths beyond the first. For the first path in the chain the distance is inherited from the unit.

I've written the following and it works however it intuitively feels clunky and slow and I'm struggling to optimise it (for performance - not specifically for code-length/style etc).

```
//set up test units with distances and pathchains
let unit1 = {distance: 5, pathChain: [["a", "b"]]};
let unit2 = {distance: 2, pathChain: [["c", "d"],["d", "e"]]};
let unit3 = {distance: 1, pathChain: [["c", "d"],["d", "a"],["a","b"]]};
let unit4 = {distance: 6, pathChain: [["a", "b"]]};
let unit5 = {distance: 3, pathChain: [["e", "f"]]};
let unit6 = {distance: 4, pathChain: [["e", "f"]]};

//assign test units to an army
let army = [unit1, unit2, unit3, unit4, unit5, unit6];

//container for results
let resultObjects = [];

//iterate over all units
for (let i = 0; i < army.length; i++){
  let unit = army[i];

  //for each unit iterate over each path chain
  for (let i2 = 0; i2 < unit.pathChain.length; i2++){
     let testingPath = unit.pathChain[i2];
     let pathFound = false;

     //testing distance is 0 unless it is the first path in the chain in which case distance is inherited from unit
     testingDistance = 0;
     if(i2 == 0){
       testingDistance = unit.distance;
     }

     //iterate over all previously seen paths
     for (let i3 = 0; i3 < resultObjects.length ; i3++){
       let resultObject = resultObjects[i3];
       let resultPath = resultObject.path;
        //test to see if we have already seen this path before
        if (testingPath[0] == resultPath[0] && testingPath[1] == resultPath[1]){
          pathFound = true;
          //if we have seen this path before but this path has a lower distance update the result record to denote a lower distance
          if (testingDistance < resultObject.minimumDistance){
            resultObject.minimumDistance = testingDistance;
          } 
        }
     }

     //if we have not seen this path before add it to the results array
     if (pathFound == false){
       let newResultObject = {path:[testingPath[0], testingPath[1]], minimumDistance: testingDistance};
       resultObjects.push(newResultObject);
     }
  }
}
console.log(resultObjects);
```

Expected output:

```
//results should be:
//[
//   {'path':['a','b'],'minimumDistance':0}
//  ,{'path':['c','d'],'minimumDistance':1}
//  ,{'path':['d','e'],'minimumDistance':0}
//  ,{'path':['d','a'],'minimumDistance':0}
//  ,{'path':['e','f'],'minimumDistance':3}
//]
```

Comment: `let resultObject = resultObjects[i3];` is only used inside the conditional, move it there to not create it unless needed

Comment: `testingDistance = 0;` is not declared, perhaps `let  testingDistance = 0;`

Comment: Yes this is an oversight from me. Suspect it'll help GC and memory if not speed. Thanks.